# knockout + chrome refresh data on submodels

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, knockout.js

I had shell view with few sub views - which looks like that and work fine.

```
<div id="shellView" style="display: none;">
<div id="tabView" data-bind="with: Tab(), visible: State() === 'Tab'">
    @Html.Partial("Tab")
</div>
<div id="tab2View" data-bind="with: Tab2(), visible: State() === 'Tab2'">
    @Html.Partial("Tab")
</div>
```

the problem is when switching beetween tabs(only on chrome). One tab has a list of images binded with knockout - all images had src to Action (RedirectResult) on controller which redirect to our server or to client server and download images:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public RedirectResult DynUrl(int id, string size)
```

Second tab is at this point empty - but when I switch to them google chrome making requests to all DynUrl's downloading again images - which is currently downloaded - just hidden.

I'm using knockout 2.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should work like

```
<div id="shellView" style="display: none;">
<!-- ko with: Tab -->
<div id="tabView" data-bind="attr: {display: isVisible}">
    @Html.Partial("Tab")
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko with: Tab2 -->
<div id="tab2View" data-bind="attr: {display: isVisible}">
    @Html.Partial("Tab")
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

and put a

```
this.isVisible = ko.computed(function(){
if(self.visibleState())return 'block';
else return 'none';
});
```

on the tab viewmodel

Comment: I'm getting: Message: ReferenceError: isVisible is not defined;  and in fact... where is the diffrence between my and your version - both focus on changing visiblity?

Comment: the key difference is that you need to use "with: Tab" instead of "with: Tab()" to get knockout to watch the referenced object for changes and apply them to the template

Comment: referenced objects get notification about changing, but on chrome it also refreshing data which isn't changed - not change exactly data, there is still src="DynUrl---parameters" but requesting that images.

Comment: so.. there is one applybinding to shellView and 'with: Tab' is to apply binding for subModel. Of course I'm thank you for the advice, just trying to undardstand it more ;-)